# Swift JSQMessagesViewController name on top

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am displaying the sender name of the receiver. However, I don't want to display the name on every single text that the person sends. For example, if he/she sends a a message consecutively, I just want it to display the name on top of the first message. I'll provide a screenshot of my chat here:

[image: screenshot of my chat]

In other words, I just want it to display the name of the user on the very 'first' message he/she sends. I tried to solve this issue, in the `attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt` with no luck.

I have tried to check if the senderId of the previous message is equal to the previous senderId - and then somehow find out if it can be shown or not. But, this has resulted in many, many failed attempts with optional errors, index out of range, and just simply not working solutions.

This is the code I have right now:

```
let message = messages[indexPath.item]

    switch message.senderId {

    case FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid:
        return nil
        break

    default:

        guard let senderDisplayName = message.senderDisplayName else {
            assertionFailure()
            return nil
        }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.left

        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: message.senderDisplayName,
                                                  attributes: [
                                                    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
                                                    NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(value: 0)
            ])

        return attributedString
        break

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem at first to solve when you first look at it. What we need to do is determine if a message is the first in a set of messages. So I created a function to determine wether or not a message is the first one sent by that person.

```
private func firstMessageInSet(indexOfMessage: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return messages[safe: indexOfMessage.item - 1]?.senderId() == messages[safe: indexOfMessage.item]?.senderId()
}
```

it simply checks the pervious message's `senderId` to see if it is the same as the current message.

Then just call that guy in this method:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    guard let message = messages[safe: indexPath.item] else { return nil }
    return firstMessageInSet(indexOfMessage: indexPath) ? nil : NSAttributedString(string: message.senderDisplayName)
}
```

This will check if its the first in the set and if it is return the senderDisplayName. Now this is using short hand but is eventually the same as

```
if firstMessageInSet(indexOfMessage: indexPath) {
   return NSAttributedString(string: message.senderDisplayName)
} else { 
  return nil
}
```

Hope that that helps you good luck with things

Comment: Hello Daniel! First off, thank you so much for trying to help me. Unfortunately, I have encountered a strange error. You see, your code did in fact work, and did not give me an 'index out of range'-error, which I got the last time. The problem now is, the name doesn't show on the 'first message'. It only shows on the second. I have tried to play with the 'firstMessageInSet' function, but with no luck. Do you happen to know why this happens? I am so close!

Comment: try sending 3 messages in a row. if it has the sender display name on the second and third messages then I may have swapped the logic for the method.

Comment: it should be this `return firstMessageInSet(indexOfMessage: indexPath) ? NSAttributedString(string: message.senderDisplayName) : nil 
}` Ill update the answer

Comment: I am sorry, I figured out why - it's because I used the switch(message.senderId), and put the code in the default, meaning - the outcome would in fact always be wrong. You see, I am trying to only display the sender name, not the receiver name (my name). But, if I only use the code you provided me, I get this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSQMessage'. This is when using the attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAt-code. But I would very much like to hide receiver name and only show sender name - that's the reason for the very first 'failed solution'.

Comment: ahh well you definitely could also check that it does not have the same senderID as the current user and pass back false in that case also.

Comment: so did you figure it all out?

Comment: This is indeed a tricky and weird problem, because - with the updated code you gave me: the name still appears on the very second of each message, but this time, when scrolling in the chat - it crashes with an 'index out of range'-error. Hmm....

Comment: After the updated code, I get an optional error again. Telling me that the conditional binding must have an optional type, not JSQMessage. I am sorry for asking so much, but I feel that I am so close - and I just can't seem to come up with a solution myself.